# Why my date input set me back to one day before react

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to submit a date with input but when i submit it set me back to one day before

Here is my following code:

```
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [timestart, setTimeStart] = useState();
  const [timeend, setTimeEnd] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const payload = {
      title,
      description,
      date,
      timestart,
      timeend,
      teamId: teamId,
    };

    const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/events/event", payload);

    location.reload();
    setShowCalendarCard(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="calendar-card-container">
      <div className="calendar-card-event-date">
        <input
          type="date"
          name="date"
          onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
        />
      ...
       );
```

When I input 05/10/2021 and then when I hit submit it set me back 05/09/2021. How can I fix this?

I think the problem is about the timezone.
Example: when I enter my date input is 05/01/2021 and then hit submit.

then I go back my postgres database it show me 04/30/2021. So basically it set back one day before.

Updated backend model of event:

Here is my model of event:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Events = sequelize.define(
    "Events",
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
      },
      title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      timestart: {
        type: DataTypes.TIME,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      timeend: {
        type: DataTypes.TIME,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    { tableName: "Events", timestamps: true }
  );
  Events.associate = function (models) {
    Events.belongsTo(models.Team, {
      foreignKey: "teamId",
    });

    Events.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "creatorId",
    });
  };
  return Events;
};
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: What does "it set me back 05/09/2021" mean? What is set back? The date in the input? The date in state? Something else?

Comment: the State i mean

Comment: Other than when submitting you don't use the `date` state in your snippet. How are you verifying/validating it is changing on you?

Comment: I do not have any validation on my backend. Just some user id validation

Comment: Yeah, timezones can be a pain, especially with vanilla JS Date objects. Try to do all your DateTime operations in the same timezone, typically UTC.

Comment: So I in model file I can do `DataTypes.Date.UTC`?

Comment: So do I need to add UTC convert for my useState?

Comment: Probably in your frontend UI, `const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());` will be local TZ. Convert to UTC when submitting to backend API. Ensure backend is parsing into UTC zone as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually putting you one month back. Basically, this date function returns the month where the month starts from 0 and ends at 11. So January is 0, February is 1, and so on. So you have to retrieve the month and increase that by one. You can take the JavaScript date() function reference from here. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp.

You can also check out this link https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_getmonth how he is adding one number to the month returned by getMonth() method.